# Using Java FX with TMC Beans

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, netbeans

currently I am completing the Java II MOOC course of the University of Helsinki. Therefore I am using TMC Beans. In part 13 GUIs are introduced, so JavaFX is required.
However, importing from JavaFX is not working, e.g.:
`import javafx.application.Application;`
it says "package javafx.application does not exist."
There aren't really instructions in the course materials to solve this problem...

What I've tried so far:

1. Installing the Plugin "Java FX Implementation for Mac OS X"
2. Downloading the Java FX SDK for Mac and
3. Creating a new global library in TMC Beans, containing the paths to all of the jar objects in
   the SDK
4. Putting the paths to the jar objects in the SDK on the used platform (JDK 14)

I'd really appreciate some advice!

Answer (score 0):

Java II MOOC uses AdoptOpenJDK ver 11. Head over to https://adoptopenjdk.net/ and download that Java version. Then change your project structure to use AdoptOpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

You should look here: https://programming-f19.mooc.fi/macos-ohjeet
You need to add TMC Beans to the list of apps that have accessibility rights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).